# Flask App Builder Default Unicode Change?

Tags: flask, floating-action-button, flask-appbuilder

Recently I know about flask app builder and try to use it on one of my project and i am try to use it to make persian website and after read the document i can't find any solution to change FAB default unicode ?
is it possible at all ?